# Rails 4: sometimes records are saved and sometimes they are not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, controller, parameter-passing

I have a weird thing happening. I have a Model call Recipe that has_many :informations and :directions. When I try to save the @recipe (see my controller) with its many :informations and :directions; sometimes it works and sometimes it does not without me changing anything to the source code.

Also, the :informations are always saved; the problem seems to only be regarding the :directions

Here is my controller:

```
    def new
        @recipe = current_user.recipes.new
    end

    def create
        @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(recipe_params)

        if @recipe.save
            redirect_to @recipe, notice: "Successfully created new recipe"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end     
    private

    def recipe_params
        params.require(:recipe).permit(:category_id, :title, :description, informations_attributes: [:id, :title, :url, :_destroy], directions_attributes: [:id, :title, :url, :step, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

When I try to save from my form here are the params:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"wfa+wTI+C3hnvscAC1O922EYlssJE3zAbEmmqMbmR+5krb0b17fkWhsXVAW1aFcom8x11uGqGO6drQudGhdcvA==",
>   "recipe"=>{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"test", "category_id"=>"3",
>   "informations_attributes"=>{"1431197959831"=>{"title"=>"test",
>   "url"=>"dede", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1431197959835"=>{"title"=>"ded",
>   "url"=>"dede", "_destroy"=>"false"}},
>   "directions_attributes"=>{"1431197963709"=>{"title"=>"dede",
>   "url"=>"dede", "step"=>"de", "_destroy"=>"false"},
>   "1431197963712"=>{"title"=>"ded", "url"=>"ded", "step"=>"ded",
>   "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Theme"}

Shema:

```
  create_table "directions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "step"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "title"
  end


  create_table "information", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
    t.integer  "cached_votes_total",      default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_score",      default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_up",         default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_down",       default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_weighted_score",   default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_weighted_total",   default: 0
    t.float    "cached_weighted_average", default: 0.0
    t.string   "title"
  end


  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :informations, :directions` in your `Recipe` model?

Comment: I believe it is not needed in rails 4 as we pass the parameters in the controller with `params.require(:recipe).permit(:category_id, :title, :description, informations_attributes: [:id, :title, :url, :_destroy], directions_attributes: [:id, :title, :url, :step, :_destroy])`

Comment: I think it is needed: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html says this is by default turned off (Rails 4.2.1), http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html says "In order to use accepts_nested_attributes_for with Strong Parameters, you will need to specify which nested attributes should be whitelisted."

Comment: Ok but anyway my records are saved properly, the thing is that sometimes it does not work for no reasons. Note that Informations always work, its the Directions that have issues sometimes. I cannot figure out why sometime it does not record.